# How to control(access) the streams of TcpClients within the threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

From some time now I'm trying to learn about Socketing programming in c#. I've been looking over many msdn, stackoverflow and codeproject projects, discussions and examples.

I rewrote them, I used debug and "step -in " in Visual Studio, I took it line by line and now I'm on "my little project." It is a mini - chat (console application). Let me describe the code and at the bottom I will give you my problems.

**Server:**

Main:

1. I've started a server, a `TcpListener` on ip 0.0.0.0 and port 8000.
2. I've created a thread on a method that accept my clients ( used 3 threads, this is one of them, the first ) and started it.

Method Accept Clients:

1. I've used a `TcpClient` to accept Tcp Clients from the `TcpListener` in a `while(true)`.
2. I've got the stream out of that client and I've created a streamReader and a streamWriter over that stream.
3. I've started a thread, the second one, in which I've done the logic for writing.
4. And I've stared the 3rd thread in witch I've done the logic for the reading.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpServer
{
    class TcpServer
    {
        static TcpListener tcpL;
        static TcpClient tcpC;
        static NetworkStream nStream;
        static StreamWriter sW;
        static StreamReader sR;
        static List<TcpClient> lTcp;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
            tcpL = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 8000);
            tcpL.Start();
            Thread accClients = new Thread(acceptClients);
            int counter = 0;
            accClients.Start(counter);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void acceptClients(object obj)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                tcpC = tcpL.AcceptTcpClient();

                Console.WriteLine(" >> Client Connected");
                nStream = tcpC.GetStream();
                sW = new StreamWriter(nStream);
                sR = new StreamReader(nStream);
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Data Transfer Established");


                Thread thWrite = new Thread(doWriteing);
                thWrite.Start(sW);
                Thread thRead = new Thread(doReading);
                thRead.Start(sR);

            }
        }

        private static void doWriteing(object obj)
        {
            StreamWriter sW = (StreamWriter)obj;
            while (true)
            {
                sW.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
                sW.Flush();
            }
        }

        private static void doReading(object obj)
        {
            StreamReader sR = (StreamReader)obj;

            while (true)
            {
                string linie;
                try
                {
                    linie = sR.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(linie);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And the Client:**

This one is quite simple.

Main:

1. I've connected the `TcpClient` on ip 127.0.0.1 and port 8000.
2. I've got the stream out of the `TcpClient`.
3. Created a `StreamWriter` and a `StreamReader` over that stream.
4. Started 2 threads for Writing and Reading.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TCPClient
{
    class TCPClient
    {
        static TcpClient tcpC;
        static NetworkStream nStream;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Client Started");
            tcpC = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8000);
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Client Connected");

            nStream = tcpC.GetStream();
            StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(nStream);
            StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(nStream);

            Thread thWrite = new Thread(doWriteing);
            thWrite.Start(sW);
            Thread thRead = new Thread(doReading);
            thRead.Start(sR);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void doWriteing(object obj)
        {
            StreamWriter sW = (StreamWriter)obj;
            while (true)
            {
                sW.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
                sW.Flush();
            }
        }

        private static void doReading(object obj)
        {
            StreamReader sR = (StreamReader)obj;
            while (true)
            {
                string linie;
                try
                {
                    linie = sR.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(linie);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have 3 big questions:

1. Why, or maybe "How", does the server send data to every thread( to only one thread at a time ) in the order they are created? Please explain this to me, I really want to understand the process. Here is a "sample"( it seems i can't post pictures ):

Serve* ( sending )

```
>  >> Server Started
>  >> Client Connected
>  >> Data Transfer Established
>  >> Client Connected
>  >> Data Transfer Established
>  >> Client Connected
>  >> Data Transfer Established
.
1 
2 
3
4
5
6
```

*Client 1* ( receiveing )

```
 >> Client Started
 >> Client Connected
1
4
```

*Client 2* ( receiveing)

```
 >> Client Started
 >> Client Connected
2
5
```

*Client 3* ( receiveing)

```
 >> Client Started
 >> Client Connected
3
6
```

2. How can I send the data received by the server to all clients ?
3. How can I store them ? What exactly to store ( and in what ) to be able to inform the server that this client id wants to send data to X client id. ( for example: client 1 wants to say "I was on the beach" to client 3 and "I was home" to client 2 )

/* I know there might appear many throws because I didn't programmed so defensively, but now I only want to learn and for me any exception that might appear can help. And I know that the first stream Flush doesn't arrive but in that case probably I've done something wrong, for that problem I'll be investigating. */

/* And important to mention: The Clients are chatting only with the server, they don't see what the others clients write. And the server receive the data in the correct order */

P.S. Please, if you take an interest in this problem, work with this code. I came here because I want to learn this things not because I search another "trick" or only to solve it.

Comment: Putting "3 questions actually" in your title warrants an automatic "too broad" flag from me. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Same than @eddie_cat, create separate questions, that way you are going to get better answers.

Comment: If I am to create 3 questions at a time I will only post the same thing 3 times in witch only the questions differs. I don't want to spam, and all of this 3 questions are linked, because all of them refers to "how to control the streams within the threads". I will modify the title so you can be happier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer the questions as best as I understand them:

Firstly you should properly add more debugging messages to your code, as this will greatly help you understand the process.  Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SBjc6tBF) where I have modified your code to include more messages so that you can better understand what read/write are doing.

> Why, or maybe "How", does the server send data to every thread( to
>   only one thread at a time ) in the order they are created? Please
>   explain this to me, I really want to understand the process. Here is a
>   "sample"( it seems i can't post pictures ):

The server is not sending data to every thread.  It is sending data to the Streams that are retrieved by the `tcpC.GetStream()`.  In the `acceptClients` function, you get the network stream for that specific client (the one that connected).  You then pass these to the new threads you create.  Each read/write thread pair then has access to their own `NetworkStream` for working with the clients.

The reason you are properly confused, is because you overwrite `tcpC` and `nStream` with the values of other clients.  The variables `tcpC` and `nStream` should really be a List.  As for each client connected, there is a `TcpClient` and a `NetworkStream`.

In other words.  On the server, for every client you have running there is 1 `TcpClient`, 1 `NetworkStream` and 2 `Threads`.

> How can I send the data recived by the server to all clients ?

What you want to do is broadcast information received to all clients (like a chat program).  To do this you will need a `List<string>` to act as a buffer.   The means on your server in the `doReading` function you will read to a list (a buffer) that will store what you read from a client.   You will then use the `doWriteing` function to write that list to clients.  You will also need a way of making sure that the server sent to all clients the messages (not just to one of them).

> client 1 wants to say "I was on the beach" to client 3

For this you will properly need a way of saying that in a command line format.   Something like

```
SEND ID TEXT
```

Where `ID` is the client # you wish to send, and every after is the message.  You can then also use something like `BROADCAST TEXT` for broadcasting to all clients.

Pastebin link again: http://pastebin.com/SBjc6tBF

Comment: Thanks for all you did, and mostly for the thing with the threads, I didn't know you can pass an array instead of only one parameter, this helps a lot and your code explain a lot

Comment: That line is just a quick way in which I used to pass more arguments to the thread.  I wanted to pass an identifier variable (the client number) to the thread, but `Thread.Start(object)` only takes an object, so I passed an object array.  Normally you would just create a structured class for passing information (like `ClientInfo`).

Comment: Yea, this really helps a lot. Both, you and @sid-hussain helped me enough and maked me understand this. Now my head explodes with so many more ideas :)).. I would give you and him an "This answare is useful" but the sistem doesn't let me, it asks for 15 rep points :-??..

Answer (score 0):

When a client connects to the server, add the client to a collection. When the server receives data that it needs to pass to all other connected clients, iterate over the collection of clients and send them the data. You will need to check if the client is still connected. Broadcasting a message to all connected clients is easier than private messaging. You simply replay the message from one client to all clients as described above. For private messaging, clients will need to send commands to the server, which indicates a clients intentions. For example a simple command might be

SEND "Hello John" TO CLIENT 3

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot, I've already did it, I only used and if and some conditions and with @jrbeverly code works greate, now I can send the msgs as a broadcast or as a private msg.

Comment: For anyone who in interested. You can have a look at this group chat. http://www.hostprojects.net/cs/30/group-chat

Comment: This gived me another view on the problem, thanks, it was very useful